# Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'socketpair'

Tags: python, eclipse, sockets, socketpair

I wanna try "`socketpair`" function in my "discovering and studying" python program language. Im creating socketpair with following command:

```
import socket

parent, child = socket.socketpair()
```

and then I get error: `Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'socketpair'`

Im working in eclipse, in windows. I suppouse socketpair working only in UNIX enviroment, but socket module should include `socketpair` anyway.

How should I fix it?

thanks

Regards

Comment: socketpair was added to the socket module in Python 2.4.  Are you using an older version of Python?

Comment: Yes, `socket.socketpair` only exists for UNIX platforms [as stated in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.socketpair). *"but socket module should include socketpair anyway."* - why? What should it do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to emulate socket.socketpair on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933411/how-to-emulate-socket-socketpair-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this is not available on Windows, but it is in development, as you can see in [related bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue18643).

You can find workaround over the net, like here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/525487-extending-socketsocketpair-to-work-on-windows/