# How to emulate socket.socketpair on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, python-3.4

The standard Python function [socket.socketpair](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socketpair) is unfortunately not available on Windows (as of Python 3.4.1), how can I write a replacement that works on both Unix and Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import socket
import errno


def create_sock_pair(port=0):
    """Create socket pair.

    If socket.socketpair isn't available, we emulate it.
    """
    # See if socketpair() is available.
    have_socketpair = hasattr(socket, 'socketpair')
    if have_socketpair:
        client_sock, srv_sock = socket.socketpair()
        return client_sock, srv_sock

    # Create a non-blocking temporary server socket
    temp_srv_sock = socket.socket()
    temp_srv_sock.setblocking(False)
    temp_srv_sock.bind(('', port))
    port = temp_srv_sock.getsockname()[1]
    temp_srv_sock.listen(1)

    # Create non-blocking client socket
    client_sock = socket.socket()
    client_sock.setblocking(False)
    try:
        client_sock.connect(('localhost', port))
    except socket.error as err:
        # EWOULDBLOCK is not an error, as the socket is non-blocking
        if err.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            raise

    # Use select to wait for connect() to succeed.
    import select
    timeout = 1
    readable = select.select([temp_srv_sock], [], [], timeout)[0]
    if temp_srv_sock not in readable:
        raise Exception('Client socket not connected in {} second(s)'.format(timeout))
    srv_sock, _ = temp_srv_sock.accept()

    return client_sock, srv_sock
```

Comment: I'd use `errno.EWOULDBLOCK` rather than the number 10035.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.5 includes Windows support for `socket.socketpair()`. For Python 2.7+, you can use the [`backports.socketpair` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.socketpair) (which I authored) on PyPi:

```
import socket
import backports.socketpair

s1, s2 = socket.socketpair()
```

Comment: Would +1 more than once if I could because both the knowledge that this problem went away starting with Python 3.5, and that there is a PyPi package to polyfill it on versions which didn't have it, answers the actual root problem that undoubtedly drives just about everyone to this question.

Comment: Please add full code, because links (even those to PyPi or GitHub) might break.  +1 anyway.